# xsl not outputting linefeed into text output and not repeating global data

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml data that is sent by an external provider. We need to output this into a fixed-width **text file** for loading into another system. The data includes a *global* element called `Stream` that should be output for each of the `Voucher`elements. But it isn't!

Here is the xml:

```
<VocaDocument xmlns:cmn="http://www.voca.com/schemas/common"  xmlns="http://www.voca.com/schemas/messaging" xmlns:iso="http://www.voca.com/schemas/common/iso" xmlns:env="http://www.voca.com/schemas/envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.voca.com/schemas/messaging http://www.voca.com/schemas/messaging/Voca_AUDDIS_AdviceofDDI_v1.0.xsd">
  <Data>
      <Document>
          <StreamStart>
              <Stream>
           <AgencyBankParameter>234</AgencyBankParameter>
          <BankName>LLOYDS BANK PLC</BankName>
          <BankCode>0004</BankCode>
          <AgencyBankName>BANK OF CYPRUS UK LTD</AgencyBankName>
          <AgencyBankCode>0234</AgencyBankCode>
          <StreamCode>01</StreamCode>
          <VoucherSortCode>SC300037</VoucherSortCode>
          <VoucherAccountNumber>46990760</VoucherAccountNumber>              
          </Stream>
          </StreamStart>
          <DDIVouchers>
              <Voucher>
                  <TransactionCode>NEW</TransactionCode> 
                  <OriginatorIdentification>
                      <ServiceUserNumber>123456</ServiceUserNumber> 
                  </OriginatorIdentification>
               </Voucher>              
               <Voucher>
                  <TransactionCode>OLD</TransactionCode> 
                  <OriginatorIdentification>
                      <ServiceUserNumber>789012</ServiceUserNumber> 
                  </OriginatorIdentification>
                  <ContactDetails>
            <PhoneNumber>020 83395862</PhoneNumber>
            <FaxNumber> FAX</FaxNumber>
              <Address>
                  <cmn:AddresseeName>RANALD LESLIE</cmn:AddresseeName>
                  <cmn:PostalName>NUFFIELD HEALTH </cmn:PostalName>
                  <cmn:AddressLine>NUFFIELD HOUSE</cmn:AddressLine>
                  <cmn:TownName>SURBITON</cmn:TownName>
                  <cmn:CountyIdentification> </cmn:CountyIdentification>
                  <cmn:CountryName>UNITED KINGDOM</cmn:CountryName>
                  <cmn:ZipCode>KT6 4BN</cmn:ZipCode>
                  </Address>
        </ContactDetails>
          <ProcessingDate>2014-08-19</ProcessingDate>
          <BankAccount><FirstLastVoucherCode>FirstLast</FirstLastVoucherCode><AgencyBankCode>0234</AgencyBankCode><SortCode>SC300037</SortCode><AccountNumber>46990760</AccountNumber><TotalVouchers>1</TotalVouchers></BankAccount>
               </Voucher>


          </DDIVouchers>
      </Document>
  </Data>
</VocaDocument>
```

I have the below xsl which I built with help from StackOverflow.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
xmlns:my="http://www.voca.com/schemas/messaging" 
xmlns:cmn="http://www.voca.com/schemas/common">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/my:MyRoot">
    <xsl:for-each select="VocaDocument/Data/Document/DDIVouchers/Voucher">
        <xsl:value-of select="../../StreamStart/Stream/AgencyBankParameter" />
        <xsl:value-of select="../../StreamStart/Stream/BankName" />

        <xsl:value-of select="ContactDetails/PhoneNumber" />
        <xsl:value-of select="ContactDetails/FaxNumber" />
        <xsl:value-of select="ContactDetails/Address/cmn:AddresseeName" />
        <xsl:value-of select="ContactDetails/Address/cmn:PostalName" />
        <xsl:value-of select="ContactDetails/Address/cmn:AddressLine" />
        <xsl:value-of select="ContactDetails/Address/cmn:TownName" />
        <xsl:value-of select="ContactDetails/Address/cmn:CountyIdentification" />
        <xsl:value-of select="ContactDetails/Address/cmn:CountryName" />
        <xsl:value-of select="ContactDetails/Address/cmn:ZipCode" />
        <xsl:value-of select="ProcessingDate" />

        <xsl:value-of select="BankAccount/SortCode" />
        <xsl:value-of select="BankAccount/AccountNumber" />
        <xsl:value-of select="BankAccount/TotalVouchers" />
        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have two problems:
1) the `Stream` elements should be repeated at the start of each line of the output and they're not - I get one at the begining, then just the `<Voucher>` records. The stamnge thing is that *without the extra namespace declarations* it **works!**

2) I want a newline/carriage return output in my texty file at the end of each line, but it's not working. I have tried this `<xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>` and this: `<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>` but neither are working.

Comment: Please post code that can be used to reproduce the problem. Your XML is incomplete, and it has no `MyRoot` element.

Comment: sorry, yes I copied it from my other post. It seems strange, your code output the `LLOYDS BANK PLC` (Stream) element twice correctly but one of the changes I have had to make has broken it

Comment: the thing seems to be that with the code that you provided, it stops working once I include the default namespace information (` 
xmlns:my="http://www.voca.com/schemas/messaging"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this along this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:msg="http://www.voca.com/schemas/messaging" 
xmlns:cmn="http://www.voca.com/schemas/common" >
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="msg:VocaDocument/msg:Data/msg:Document/msg:DDIVouchers/msg:Voucher">
        <xsl:value-of select="../../msg:StreamStart/msg:Stream/msg:AgencyBankParameter" />
        <xsl:value-of select="../../msg:StreamStart/msg:Stream/msg:BankName" />

        <xsl:value-of select="msg:BankAccount/msg:SortCode" />
        <xsl:value-of select="msg:BankAccount/msg:AccountNumber" />
        <xsl:value-of select="msg:BankAccount/msg:TotalVouchers" />

        <!-- NOTE HOW TO EXTRACT AN ADDRESS ELEMENT THAT HAS ITS OWN NAMESPACE -->
        <xsl:value-of select="msg:ContactDetails/msg:Address/cmn:AddresseeName" />

        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*Note that by default, child elements inherit their parent's namespace.*

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help, patience and taking the time to help me with this.